# SSRS reports cannot be opened after deleting encryption key

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Recently we have migrated SSRS from SQL Server 2005 to 2012 running on Windows 8. We deleted encryption key after observing that the reporting server was inaccessible. Then we were able to access the reporting server from the Internet Explorer on the same machine, and were able to list the existing reports in the browser. But when we try to open any report, login name and password are required before viewing any report.  The expected behavior is that the reports should be opened without necessity to provide login/password.

Question: is this caused by deletion of encryption key? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the Datasources for your reports and check the credentials that are stored against them.  You may need to resave these credentials to create a new encryption key.  Click 'Test Connection' to see if you are successful.

Your reports should work fine once you have re-established a safe connection between report and the server.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Reporting Services Configuration Tool
Start the Reporting Services Configuration tool, and then connect to the report server instance you want to configure.
Click Encryption Keys, and then click Delete. Click OK.
Restart the Report Server Windows Service.
Using the rskeymgmt utility
Run rskeymgmt.exe locally on the computer that hosts the report server. Use the following syntax: rskeymgmt –d
Restart the Report Server Windows Service.
To re-specify encrypted values, you need to retype the connection string for each data source and retype the user name and password for each data source that uses stored credentials.
Refer my article

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52585.ssrs-troubleshooting-the-report-server-was-unable-to-validate-the-integrity-of-encrypted-data-in-the-database.aspx